# Pausing Timer on Javascript Scoreboard doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

i would like to know how to fix my problem. I want my timer on my scoreboard to start when the integer click = 1 and when the spacebar is down, and to pause when click = 2 and when the spacebar is down. When i try to do this, the function commencing() is being called each time that its pressed, making the timer go faster and faster. Here's a code sample:

```
var minutes = 0;
var c = 0;
var secondes = 0;
var click = 0;

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 32:
                    click = click + 1;
                    if (click = 1) {
                       var commence = setInterval(commencing, 1000); 
                    } else if (click = 2) {
                       clearInterval(commence);
                       click = 0; 
                    }
                break;    
            }
    });

    function commencing(){  
                            secondes -= 1;
                            document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + secondes;
                        if (secondes < 10) {
                            document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + c + secondes;
                        }    
                        if (secondes < 1) {
                            secondes = 60;
                            minutes = minutes - 1;
                            if (minutes < 0) {
                                clearInterval(commencing);
                                minutes = 0;
                                secondes = 0;
                            }
                        }   
                      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define variable `commence` outside the function as a global variable.

Comment: I have defined the variable `commence` as a local variable. However, the timer starts as soon as the webpage is loaded, even when i used the integer `click` to define when to start it. But in the bright side, it can pause. Here's the code: `case 32:
                click = click + 1;
                if (click = 2) {
                   clearInterval(commence);
                   click = 0;
                }
            break;    `

Comment: Yes. You defined `commence` as a local variable, thus thus every on handler execution this variable initialize by `undefined` and lost they value after handler's execution ends. 
Moreover  both of your `if` statements in handler did not check the condition but assign value to click. And `else` branch of `if (click=1)` is never executed.

Comment: First of all - replace assignment with comaration in `if` (i.e you need `click === 2` instead of `click = 2`). Second one - define commence outside handler, in same place where you define `click` and other variables for example. Last but not least - replace `clearInterval(commencing)` with `clearInterval(commence)` in your commencing function

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i'm marking this as the best answer! :).

Comment: I have another small problem that doesn't really seem to matter, when i set the timer to 5:00, the last digit of it, which is the zero, goes at -1, then it goes at 59. It goes at 5:0-1 to 4:59. Is there are problem inside my `commencing()` function?